# Object Field in Spring form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm newbie in Spring MVC and I've faced some troubles.

I have Domain model like this:

```
public class BlogEntry {
private long id;
private User author;
private String articleName;
private String articleText;
private Date date;

public BlogEntry(){

}
```

It is with getters and setter of course.

I've got JSP with form built with spring form tags:

```
<form:form action="/admin/addEntry" method="post" modelAttribute="entry">
<form:input path="articleName"></form:input><br/>
<form:textarea path="articleText"></form:textarea><br/>
<form:select path="author" >
  <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <form:option value="${user.name}"/>

  </c:forEach>
</form:select><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Add Entry">
```

In this form author is representing the String. I need it to be the instance of User class. How can I achieve that?

Comment: It seems the selected value (value="${user.name}") is being set as the author object. Try to use value=$user and put the username as its text.

Comment: How it will decide what field of User class it will correspond to?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using

```
<form:select path="author" items="${users}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="nickName">
```